# Unable to return variable. "java: cannot find variable"

Tags: java

The goal is to find the largest numerical palindrome created by multiplying two three digit numbers.

```
public static void main (String[]args)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int temp = 0;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++){
        for (int z = 100; z <= 999; z++){
            int prod = i * z;
            result = pal(prod);
            answers.add(result);
        }
    }
    int answer = Collections.max(answers);
    System.out.println(answer);
}

public static int pal(int n){
    String temp2 = String.valueOf(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < temp2.length()/2; i++){
        if (temp2.charAt(i) != temp2.charAt(temp2.length()-1-i)) {
            int palindrome = Integer.parseInt(temp2);
            return palindrome;
        }
    }
    return palindrome;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`palindrome` is not visible outside the loop's if-statement in `pal`:

```
public static int pal(int n){
    String temp2 = String.valueOf(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < temp2.length()/2; i++){
        if (temp2.charAt(i) != temp2.charAt(temp2.length()-1-i)) {
            int palindrome = Integer.parseInt(temp2); // defined here
            return palindrome;
        }
    }
    // palindrome is not defined here
    // return something else instead
    return palindrome;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the palindrome variable to a visible block for the return statement . Like this:

```
public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int temp = 0;
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++){
            for (int z = 100; z <= 999; z++){
                int prod = i * z;
                result = pal(prod);
                answers.add(result);
            }
        }
        int answer = Collections.max(answers);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    public static int pal(int n){
        int palindrome; //You could place it here.
        String temp2 = String.valueOf(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < temp2.length()/2; i++){
            if (temp2.charAt(i) != temp2.charAt(temp2.length()-1-i)) {
                palindrome = Integer.parseInt(temp2);
                return palindrome;
            }
        }
        return palindrome;
    }
    }
```

Check this: [Block scope variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499554/block-scope-variables)

EDIT:

Initialize the variable or you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Reut Sharabani's answer, it also appears that you wish to return the int n provided to your pal method every time pal is called.

```
if (temp2.charAt(i) != temp2.charAt(temp2.length()-1-i)) { //if it is not a palindrome
    int palindrome = Integer.parseInt(temp2); //you return it
    return palindrome;
}
```

This means you will add all numbers tested to your ArrayList.

I suggest changing the method's return type to boolean, so you can return true or false depending on whether or not the number is a palindrome. Then, you check if pal(n) == true, and if so, you add it to the ArrayList.