# Java nested scopes and variables' name hiding

Tags: java, c++, name-hiding

I'm learning name look up in Java, and coming from C++ I found interesting that even if Java lets me nest however many blocks of code,I am allowed to hide a name only in the first nested scope:

```
// name hiding-shadowing: local variables hide names in class scope

class C {

  int a=11;

  {
    double a=0.2; 

  //{
  //  int a;             // error: a is already declared in instance initializer
  //}

  }

  void hide(short a) {  // local variable a,hides instance variable
    byte s;
    for (int s=0;;);    // error: s in block scope redeclares a
    {
      long a=100L;      // error: a is already declared in (method) local scope
      String s;         //error: s is alredy defined in (method) local scope 
    }                   
  }

}
```

this is weird from a C++ perspective,since there I can nest how many scopes I want,AND I'm able to hide variables as I like. Is this the normal behaviour of Java or am I missing something?

Comment: this is the normal behavior.

Comment: actually your paradigm coming from C++ is erroneous, you must adapt your mind to Java way of thinking

Comment: For future Googler: see also [*Block scope variables*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499554/block-scope-variables).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not about the "first nested scope" - it's a matter of Java allowing a local variable to hide a field, but not allowing it to hide *another* local variable. Presumably the designers of Java believed such hiding to be bad for readability.

Note that your example of a local variable in an instance initializer does *not* create an error - this code is valid:

```
class C {
  int a = 11;

  {
    // Local variable hiding a field. No problem.
    double a = 0.2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice to get an answer from you... `:)`

Comment: Correct answer !! Classic case of someone trying to use a language before reading through the first chapter :-)

Comment: yes,thanks for the clarification about nesting.. I noticed that even if I declare a new name into a local scope ( initializer block,method or loop ) that doesn't hide a field I cannot hide that name,the compiler complains

Comment: @Geek the anwer is correct indeed and you're just guessing wrong since I've been studying C++ and Java for 6 months now, but I guess you learn everything on page one of your manual,good for you!

Comment: @Luca: Yes, exactly - you can't hide one local variable with another.

Comment: @Luca : No offense intended. Happy Learning !!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a C++ guy but that really looks weird from C++ side and If I were the designer , I completely remove that behaviour. That really causes bugs and hard to read the code.

To lead  a peaceful life in Java that behaviour is completely removed. Compiler shows you an error if you try to do that as you are seeing it now.