# Java: Is it possible to have variables of the same name in one method seperated by an if statement

Tags: java

I have a piece of code which sets a String to a value depending on an if statement:

```
if (a == 1) {
String txt = "Yes";
}
else if (a == 2) {
String txt = "No";
}
```

I realise I could define the txt variable outside of the if-else statement but I would like to know if this is possible and won't cause any issues.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is fine, but `txt` will not exist outside the `if` blocks.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? If your question is literally "is this possible" then the compiler is the best authority on the matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block scope variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499554/block-scope-variables)

Answer (score 2):

It will work, but only if you use that value within the statement only. You can't reference variables declared within an if-statement outside of the if-statement. To get around this you can declare the variable before the if-statement:

```
String txt;

if (a == 1) {
    txt = "Yes";
}
else if (a == 2) {
    txt = "No";
}
```

Then you can continue to use the variable txt elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible but will it cause any issues? it depends on where you want to use 'txt' value what you want to do with value

you can check detail on scope of declaration here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3